# What is corresponding .net usercontrol in java?

Tags: java, swing, javabeans

For .net developers usercontrols are vital. I am trying to develop a java swing application. I want to create my custom "usercontrols", just like in .net. But there is no usercontrol :).

In some places i see something like "javabean" but it is not clear ? Can anyone guide me ? 
How can i create a usercontrol in java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Grook's link explains the basics of swing components. But for me , I need something more special and easy solution.

Basically a jpanel is similar to a usercontrol in .net.

Here is a good tutorial that explains using jpanels and their reusability which is so similar to .net usercontrols.

http://video.codegear.com/jbuilder/2008/SwingDesigner/VisualInheritance/Visual%20Inheritance.htm

- the video is about jbuilder IDE but it is the similar on netbeans .

Comment: your question wasn't clear enough - me too thought (after googling for ".net usercontrol") that you were after a custom component. Anyway, glad you found what you need :-)